# MQTT Sensor provides too much data

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have a setting with:

- MQTT temperature sensor
- Mosquitto broker
- Azure Cloud

The problem is that the sensor sends data every minute and there is no way to reduce these intervals to every 15 minutes (in Device).

Is there a possibility with the Mosquitto Broker to receive data only every 15 minutes or to forward the data to the cloud only every 15 minutes?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

A real simple way to do this is to use Node-Red with an MQTT receiver node and connect it to a RateLimit node, setting it to 1 every 15 min. Modify the topic on the outbound send to something else and use that topic for the Azure Cloud.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Unfortunately the broker runs on a router (Teltonika RUT240) I think there is not enough space for node-red. Is it possible to set it up in the Mosquitto?

Comment: Unless the router is your only compute resource, install Node-Red somewhere else....as long as there is a network connection between them, it will work.  That's part of the beauty of MQTT -- nodes can be anywhere, running on anything, as long as there is a network connection between them.

Comment: The router is the only compute resource, the rest are Sensors :-(